# How do I print an expanded macro in Scala?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-2.10

I am writing a macro in Scala, but when I call it I get an error message saying "Double does not take parameters". Clearly there is something wrong with how the macro builds the AST. So how can I see the expanded macro? Is there a way to call the macro implementation at runtime?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Provide `-Ymacro-debug-lite` or `-Ymacro-debug-verbose` option to the compiler.

Off the top of my head, detalization of printed ASTs is governed by `-Yshow-trees-compact`, `-Yshow-trees-stringified`, `-Xprint-types`, `-uniqid` and `-Yshow-symkinds`. You can find other gems by running `scala -X` and `scala -Y` (or inspecting the sources of scala settings at https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.10.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/settings/ScalaSettings.scala).

Also, despite being essentially a macro, reification has its own tracing mechanism that can be configured by `-Yreify-copypaste` and `-Yreify-debug`.

Answer (score 2):

There is [Macrocosm's desugar](https://github.com/retronym/macrocosm/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/retronym/macrocosm/Macrocosm.scala) which can show how your source code, including, but no limited to macros, is transformed into.

```
    println("TRANSFORMATION:\n"+ desugar{
        println("a string") 
        MY_MACRO("something")
    })
```

Comment: I just tried that, but since the expanded macro does not typecheck, it won't typecheck either when I wrap it in a call to desugar.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that I misunderstood your question indeed. If MY_MACRO fails, there is no way that my example compiles!

Comment: In that case, so far I have used scala.reflect.makro.FrontEnds#echo() with Eclipse, which is the painful equivalent of debugging a runtime with println()... better than nothing though :)

Comment: That helps a little bit, but there has to be a way to view the whole generated tree.

Comment: Back to the error though, couldn't it be an Apply(Double,...) instead of Apply(Double.apply,...)? <pseudocode>

Comment: No, the error message is talking about the _type_ Double. It does not take type parameters.