# What's the recommended way to pass the results of macro computations to run-time?

Tags: sql, scala, macros, compilation

I'm trying to build some SQL-like abstraction and I have hit a problem.

This is a simplified “database table”:

```
trait Coffee {
  def id: Long
  def name: String
  def brand: String
}
```

This is my query abstraction:

```
import language.experimental.macros

object Query {  
  def from[T] = 
    macro QueryMacros.fromMacro[T]
}

class From[T] {  
  def select[S](s: T => S): Select[T] =
    macro QueryMacros.selectMacro[T, S]
}

class Select[T] {
  def where(pred: T => Boolean): Where =
    macro QueryMacros.whereMacro[T]
}

class Where(val result: String)
```

This is my macro implementation:

```
import scala.reflect.macros.Context

object QueryMacros {
  val result = new StringBuilder

  def fromMacro[T : c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context): c.Expr[From[T]] = { 
    result ++= ("FROM " + c.weakTypeOf[T])
    c.universe.reify(new From[T])
  }

  def selectMacro[T : c.WeakTypeTag, S : c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(s: c.Expr[T => S]): c.Expr[Select[T]] = {
    result ++= ("SELECT " + s.tree)
    c.universe.reify(new Select[T])
  }

  def whereMacro[S](c: Context)(pred: c.Expr[S]): c.Expr[Where] = {
    result ++= ("WHERE " + pred.tree)
    c.universe.reify(new Where(result.toString))
  }
}
```

And this is my example code:

```
object Main extends App {
  println("Query start")
  val query = 
    Query.from[Coffee]
         .select(_.id)
         .where(_.brand == "FairTrade")

  println(query.result)
  println("Query end")
}
```

It compiles and runs fine, but the output is:

```
Query start

Query end
```

Basically, `result` seems to be empty. I expected that it would hold the accumulated strings of the trees.

How can I pass my data from the macro compile stage to the next stage, so it shows up at runtime?
I could of course pass the current string to the next method  explicitly, but I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you need to have a `Queryable` abstraction that: 1) provides the collection API (`from`, `select`, etc), 2) remembers the methods that were called on it by reifying the calls and accumulating them inside.

This concept is somewhat explained in our ScalaDays slides [1] and is implemented in Slick (which is open source) [2]. By the way in LINQ they do roughly the same with methods on `Queryable` reifying the calls and feeding them to your object that implements `IQueryable`, e.g. as described in [3].

Links:

1. http://scalamacros.org/talks/2012-04-18-ScalaDays2012.pdf
2. https://github.com/slick/slick/tree/master/src/main/scala/scala/slick/queryable
3. http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2007/04/06/the-iqueryable-tales-linq-to-ldap-part-1-key-concepts.aspx

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks, I'll have a look. Looks like there is one true solution. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not passing the information from one macro call to the next one. All of those happen at compile time, so that should work. The problem is with the macro that is called last. Since it returns `c.universe.reify(new Where(result.toString))`, `new Where(result.toString)` is called at runtime. And then `result` will be empty. What you can do is return `c.Expr(tree)`, where `tree` applies `Where`'s constructor to a `String` literal that contains `result.toString`.

Also, you should note that your code depends on the order in which the macro calls are compiled. If you have several calls to these macros in several code files, `result` might contains information from previous calls. It would probably be best to rethink your whole approach.

Comment: Yes, it was just some prototype to work around the fact that I wanted to print the trees at compile-time, but I couldn't make Eclipse show the compile-time output to me. :-) Do you have an idea of a better solution?

Comment: You mean like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677609/how-do-i-print-an-expanded-macro-in-scala

Answer (score 0):

As @Kim points out aggregating the information is not the problem but that the macro expansion will generate code that evaluates `result.toString` at runtime when it is indeed empty. I had a similar problem as you and ended up doing the equivalent replacing `result.toString` with `resultExpr(c).splice`

```
private def resultExpr(c :Context) = { 
  import c.universe._
   c.Expr[String](Literal(Constant(result.toString)))
}
```

(As @Kim also points out this will feed the accumulated results of all macro calls back to the runtime, so beware!)