# Pass functions as parameters to Scala macro

Tags: scala, macros

I was debugging some code related to Scala macros.

`m` is a def macro, which takes a function as its parameter:

```
def m(f: T => Boolean) = macro xxx
```

There is another function `g: T => Boolean`. I found different behaviors by passing different lambda expressions to `m`:

1. `(x: T) => g(x)`
2. `(x: T) => (() => g(x))()`

Is there a proper way to debug such cases? If I'm not mistaken, the parameters are expanded to AST and passed to the macro at compile time. How can I debug the compiled AST?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055210/whats-the-easiest-way-to-use-reify-get-an-ast-of-an-expression-in-scala and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677609/how-do-i-print-an-expanded-macro-in-scala might be helpful.

Comment: I'm afraid those examples weren't clear to me.  I am seeking to do the same thing as this poster.  Inside a quasiquote I want to invoke f.  The obvious thing of $f(someT) didn't work.  How can you unscramble the AST to behave like a function call (i.e. pass something to it and invoke it)?